# Fill textstroke() with white in canvas while keeping the black outline

Tags: html, canvas

Everything is woorking in this script.
the outline of text is black which is fine. Just the inside needs to be filled with white keeping the same background image.

```
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="800" height="800"></canvas>

  <script>

    var c = document.querySelector("#c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function(){
      console.log("Loaded image");

      // do something else
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
      ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.font = "bold 36pt impact";
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;

      ctx.strokeText("Hello Hello!", 50, 50);

    }
    image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HgIv.png";
  //ctx.strokeText("Hello Hello!", 50, 50);

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Like this...?**

[image]

```js
var c = document.querySelector("#c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();

image.onload = function(){
  console.log("Loaded image");

  // do something else
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
  ctx.font = "bold 36pt impact";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;

  ctx.fillText("Hello Hello!", 50, 50);
  ctx.strokeText("Hello Hello!", 50, 50);

}
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HgIv.png";
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```